# reloadGrid does not reload colData from Ajax function

Tags: jquery

I've a simple jqgrid table (armando_rampas). Its colNames, colModel and colData come from an ajax with json.

The first load time (armando_rampas_fn();) I get a table with Data, but when I try to refresh it, the reloadgrid loses the data.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() 
{
        function armando_rampas_fn()
        {
            $.ajax(
                {
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "json/columnas_ipphone?wl=es",
                   data: "",
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: function(data)
                   {
                       colN = data.colNames;
                       colM = data.colModel;
                       colD = data.colData;

                       jQuery("#armando_rampas").jqGrid({
                            //url:'json/ipphone_list_json.php',
                            datatype: 'jsonstring',                     
                            colNames: colN,
                            colModel: colM,
                            datastr: colD,
                            height:'auto',
                            width:'650', 
                            //loadui: 'disable',         
                        });

                    },
                });

        setTimeout(function()
            {
            armando_rampas_fn();
            jQuery("#armando_rampas").trigger('reloadGrid');
            }, 1000);

        };

        armando_rampas_fn();

});
```

Does anybody knows how can I refresh the jqgrid with the new values from colNames, colModel and colData?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well this would be kinda hard since you change the structure of the grid maybe have presets and save the configuration somewhere an load it or whatever.
Check this:
http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:import_methods

Comment: Hello!! I've got it using setTimeout(function(){
   armando_rampas_fn();
   jQuery("#armando_rampas").jqGrid('setGridParam', {datatype:'jsonstring', datastr:'colD', colNames:'colN'}).trigger("reloadGrid");
   }, 1000);

  };

Comment: But if colNames or colModel change, the reloadgrid does not re-construct the number of cols....

Comment: Hi,

My final code that solves "my" problem.... but now the table is blinking continuously

    setTimeout(function(){
       armando_rampas_fn();
       $('#armando_rampas').jqGrid('GridUnload');
       jQuery("#armando_rampas").jqGrid('setGridParam', {datatype:'jsonstring', datastr:'colD', colNames:'colN'}).trigger("reloadGrid");
       }, 1000);